# Solving One Equation with Two Variables

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, homework

I am trying to solve an equation with two variables. It is the last step in the process of using the method of undetermined coefficients to solve a nonhomogeneous differential equation. The equation is this:

$$y''-5y'+6y=e^tcos(2t)+e^{2t}(3t+4)sin(t)$$

My first particular equation is

$$Y(t)=e^t(Acos(2t)+Bsin(2t))$$

and I need to find A and B values that satisfy:

$$y''-5y'+6y=e^tcos(2t)$$

Plugging $Y(t)$ into the equation gives:

$$-2 e^t ((A+3B) cos(2 t)-(3 A + B) sin(2 t))=e^tcos(2t)$$

So A and B must satisfy:

$$A+3B=-1/2$$
$$B-3A=0$$

And then A and B are easy to solve for.

However, putting the equation into Solve[] gives an error:

```
Solve[{-2 Exp[t] ((a + 3 b) Cos[2 t] + (-3 a + b) Sin[2 t]) == Exp[t] Cos[2 t]}, {a, b}]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

And the output just gives B in terms of A and t. This particular problem I can solve on paper, but others are much more complex. I need a way to solve an equation like this using Mathematica to save time. This is homework from Boyce Elementary Differential Equations 10, Section 3.5 #23.

EDIT: Made variable names lower case

Comment: `Solve[{-2 Exp[t] ((n + 3 m) Cos[2 t] + (-3 n + m) Sin[2 t]) == Exp[t] Cos[2 t]}, {n, m}]` which gives me `{{n -> -0.05, m -> -0.15}}`. You probably assigned something different to `A` and `B`, so you need to clear them. Also, it is not a good practice to use upper-case letters as vars, functions, etc as they are built-in symbols.

Comment: I copy/pasted your input into a freshly re-booted kernel and got the same error. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Whoa :D What is your version of *Mathematica* ?

Comment: 8.0 for students

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Do you have access to other versions of *Mathematica* ? If so please try to evaluate the input there.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to solve problems of this type: create a system of at least two independent equations for the two variables `a` and `b`. How to do this if you only have one equation to begin with?

In your case one side of the equation (`Exp[t] Cos[2 t]`) is independent of the unknowns, so I just evaluate that side at some specific values of `t` and use those as new right-hand sides to which the left-hand side must be matched. This can be solved with `FindFit`:

```
Rationalize@FindFit[Table[{t, Exp[t] Cos[2 t]},
   {t, 0, 10, .1}],
  -2 Exp[t] ((a + 3 b) Cos[2 t] + (-3 a + b) Sin[2 t]),
  {a, b}, t]

(* ==> {a -> -(1/20), b -> -(3/20)} *)
```

**Alternatively**, you could evaluate both sides of the equation at discrete times and create a matrix equation from that. Then apply `LeastSquares` to solve that equation.

**Alternatively to all of the above**, one can also avoid having to pick the "right" `t` values at which the system of equations becomes linearly independent by doing the whole thing in Fourier space:

```
eqn = -2 Exp[t] ((a + 3 b) Cos[2 t] + (-3 a + b) Sin[2 t]) ==
    Exp[t] Cos[2 t];

Solve[
 Table[Map[FourierCoefficient[#, t, i] &, eqn], {i, 0, 1}],
 {a, b}]

(* ==> {{a -> -(1/20), b -> -(3/20)}} *)
```

This is probably the cleanest approach mathematically, because the different Fourier components are guaranteed to be linearly independent. If you have more than 2 unknowns, you just increase the upper limit in `Table` from `1` to the required number of equations.

Answer (score 5):

You want to extract coefficients of terms in `Cos[t]` and other functions of `t` and find values of `{A, B}` that make these terms vanish. `SolveAlways` can do this sometimes (works reliably when input is polynomial, say).

```
SolveAlways[
 TrigExpand@{-2 Exp[t] ((A + 3 B) Cos[2 t] + (-3 A + B) Sin[2 t]) == 
    Exp[t] Cos[2 t]}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}]
```

> During evaluation of In[16]:= SolveAlways::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by SolveAlways, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(* Out[16]= {{A -> -(1/20), B -> -(3/20)}, {t -> -∞}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to yet distinct from the other solutions.  Substitute two values for `t` (not a period apart), to create two independent equations. Then you will get a unique solution.

```
Solve[-2 Exp[t] ((n + 3 m) Cos[2 t] + (-3 n + m) Sin[2 t]) == 
   Exp[t] Cos[2 t] /. {{t -> 0}, {t -> 1}}, {n, m}]
(*
  {{n -> -(1/20), m -> -(3/20)}}
*)
```

(Of course, the replacements `{{t -> 0}, {t -> Pi/4}}` yield the system in the OP's question.  It gives the same answer.)

---

For a more rigorous approach, make your system from the equation and its derivative.  Then

```
Solve[
 {#, D[#, t]} &[
   -2 Exp[2 t] ((n + 3 m) Cos[2 t] + Exp[t] (-3 n + m) Sin[2 t]) == Exp[2 t] Cos[2 t]
   ],
 {n, m}]
(*
  {{n -> -(1/20), m -> -(3/20)}}
*)
```

Since the determinant of the coefficients

```
Block[{y},
 y[t_] := -2 Exp[t] ((n + 3 m) Cos[2 t] + (-3 n + m) Sin[2 t]);
 Det[{Coefficient[y[t], {m, n}], Coefficient[y'[t], {m, n}]}] // Simplify
 ]
(*
  -80 E^(2 t)
*)
```

is nonzero, the equations will be independent.  More generally, if the determinant were zero, then the coefficients of `m`, `n` would be proportional.  That in turn implies `y'[t]` is a constant multiple of `y[t]`.  Hence `y[t]` would have to be an exponential function, which it is not in this case.

Comment: Youse guys are too smart.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Either that, or we lack any respect for mathematical rigor...

Comment: @Jens My way might be likened more to mathematical rigor mortis. (As for yours, one can always show a posteriori that it was correct.)