# Plotting/Solving one equation in two variables

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to find solutions of an equation in two variables `k` and `n`. Alternatively, I would also be okay with a plot which shows the variation of one versus another.

```
Nnorm[n_] := 
  Sqrt[2]*(1 - 2/(n + 1/6))^(1/4)*(1 - 2/n)^(-1/
   2)*(1 - 2/(n + 1/12))^(1/2);

F[u_, L_, k_, w_] := 
  u^2/(8 Pi*L*Sqrt[1 + (L/(2 k))^2])*Cos[2*w*k*ArcSinh[L/(2 k)]];
```

The value of parameters `u`, `L`, `w` are known. After using `FullSimplify[F[0.01, L, k, 10]]`and my requirement between relation of `F` and `Nnorm` : `F = -0.00003*Nnorm` I will obtain an equation like this :

```
 (7.957747154594767`*^-6 Cos[20 k ArcCsch[(2 k)/L]])/(
  L Sqrt[4 + L^2/k^2]) + (0.00003*(
    2 n (1 - 2/(1/12 + n)) Sqrt[1 - 2/(1/6 + n)])/(-2 + n)) == 0
```

This is what I want to solve or plot, an equation in two variables. The only thing that partially works is the following :

```
F[0.001, 100, 200, 10];

(* obtaining the value of F here and then manually substituting as follows : *)

Solve[-0.00003*2*(1 - 2/(n + 1/6))^(1/
   2)*(1 - 2/n)*(1 - 2/(n + 1/12)) == 3.55881271708, n]
```

This doesn't always work so I cannot put this in a loop or an `Export` command.

I have tried using `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Solve`, `ContourPlot`, `Reduce`, `InverseFunction`to no avail.

I cannot use `FindRoot` by taking some value for either `k` or `n` and using it on the other because I simply have no idea what to give for starting value for the `FindRoot` function.

I have also looked at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50609/solving-one-equation-with-two-variables), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177225/plot-two-variables-one-versus-the-other) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180304/how-to-plot-an-equation-with-two-variables-in-2d) at the very least.

The main culprit here, I think, is `ArcSinh` without which `Solve` will probably do the job. I tried to eliminate `ArcSinh` by comparing the values of `L` and `k` but again nothing.

Please give me some help on how to tackle this issue.

Edit : 
I use

```
Plot3D[{F[1/1000, 10^90, k, 10], -3*^-5*(Binomial[n, 2])^-1}, {n, 
  10^16, 10^17}, {k, 10^60, 10^61}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 110, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

to get

[image: n from 10^16 to 10^17]

For any higher values of n the plot disappears and this plot also seems to be missing things compared to the answer below. Can I say that for `n=6.4*10^16` the constraint I require is satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Nnorm[n_] := 
  Sqrt[2]*(1 - 2/(n + 1/6))^(1/4)*(1 - 2/n)^(-1/2)*(1 - 2/(n + 1/12))^(1/2);

FunctionDomain[Nnorm[n], n]

(* n < -(1/6) || n > 2 *)
```

However, if `Nnorm` is simplified for `n > 0`

```
FunctionDomain[Simplify[Nnorm[n], n > 0], n] //
 Simplify[#, n > 0] &

(* 11/6 <= n < 23/12 || n > 2 *)
```

Plotting

```
Plot[-3*^-5*Nnorm[n], {n, -2, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

```
F[u_, L_, k_, w_] := 
  u^2/(8 Pi*L*Sqrt[1 + (L/(2 k))^2])*Cos[2*w*k*ArcSinh[L/(2 k)]];

Plot3D[
 {F[1/1000, 100, k, 10], -3*^-5*Nnorm[n]},
 {n, 11/6, 23/12}, {k, 0, 200},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
sol1[k_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[
    F[1/1000, 100, k, 10] == -3*^-5*Nnorm[n],
    {n, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@
  {11/6, 23/12 - 1*^-6}

sol1[200]

(* {{n -> 1.83333333333333}, {n -> 1.91666666622529}} *)

sol2[k_?NumericQ] := NSolve[{11/6 <= n < 23/12,
   F[1/1000, 100, k, 10] == -3*^-5*Nnorm[n]},
  n, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

sol2[200]

(* {{n -> 1.91666666663313}, {n -> 1.83333333333333}} *)

% /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]

(* {{n -> 23/12}, {n -> 11/6}} *)
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand your answer better? Since I had no idea about what to give as initial value to `FindRoot` you found the domain of `Nnorm`. I am interested in the range of `n>0` or even `n>2`. I don't understand why you did the 3D plot.  Then you give 2 ways to solve for constraint between `F` & `Nnorm`. I could use either of them with a loop or `Export` to generate a data file with values of `n` & `k`. Perfect. The only problem is that for some reason this is not working for `n>2`. I get the output as `{}`. Was the reason to do 3D plot to show what values of `n` work?

Comment: When I use `sol2[k_?NumericQ] := NSolve[{3 <= n < 5, F[1/1000, 100, k, 10] == 3*^-5*Nnorm[n]}, n, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` and `sol2[200]` I get the output : `{}`

Comment: Since you said that you tried `ContourPlot` it appeared that you were looking for real-valued solutions. `Nnorm` has a very limited range where it is real and takes values such that `F == -0.00003*Nnorm` for the values of `u`, `L`, and `w` that you gave. The plot above was used to determine how to estimate the initial values for `FindRoot`. In this case, constants could be used over a wide range of `k`. `sol2` works with v12.1, perhaps you are using a different version. `sol2` is not needed if `sol1` works for you since they should give identical results.

Comment: Actually, please let me modify it a little bit. I had used an approximation for factorial. Original equation that I need to solve would be this : `-0.00003 = Binomial[n,2]*(3.97887*10^-8 Cos[200 k ArcSinh[L/(2 k)]])/(L Sqrt[1 + L^2/(4 k^2)])` for various values of L, specially when L>>k. Inspired from your answer I have been using `Plot3D` to get the available regions for n which is also quite large maybe of order `10^23` but I am not getting anything. I am posting some outputs, if possible please look at them and give me a little bit more help.